# Prometheus http_requests_total returns request status "Hxx"

Tags: prometheus

Prometheus http_requests_total returns request status "Hxx" for POST method, what does it mean?

I use prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator for python

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I just got into the same issue and actually found a solution!

What happens is that you are probably somewhere returning something like:

```
from http import HTTPStatus

def f():
    ...
    return JSONResponse(status_code=HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND, detail="Item was not found")
```

and Prometheus when grouping is just saying:

```
status = your_status[0] + "xx"
```

which results in `Hxx` since `H` is the first in your "status". Easy fix is to just do `int(HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND)` or wait for an update from instrumentator devs.